# Visual Studio 2015 Import d3 Cannot Find Module 'd3'

Tags: d3.js, visual-studio-2015, npm

I am developing an Angular project which uses d3 (v4) in some of its components. I am using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) and I have Typescript for Visual Studio v1.8.36.0 installed. I have Node v6.10.2 installed.

I have installed d3 both by editing my `package.json` file directly and by performing an `npm install --save`. I have `"d3": "^4.9.1"` listed in my `package.json` file.

My project uses Webpack and in my `webpack.config.vendor.js` file in the `vendor` section I have `'d3'` listed.

I checked in my project's `node_modules` folder and within `@types` I can see the top level d3 folder and all the individual d3 module's type definitions. Also all of the d3 framework folders are within `node_modules`.

D3 is working fine, I just have no intellisense and my import setting `import * as d3 from "d3";` displays an error under `"d3"` saying 'cannot find module d3'.

Curiously I also work on this project on a Mac laptop running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015 and everything is fine on that computer when I sync up the project in Team Explorer and continue working.

I have followed many suggestions to try and sort this out but nothing yet has helped. Can anyone suggest what I am missing please?

Comment: What kind of file is the `import` statement in?

Comment: A Typescript file for an Angular 4 component.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this problem was fixed by re-installing Typescript for Visual Studio.